# Jquery Data Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, backbone.js, coffeescript

so I filled a dropdown programatically like this -

```
optionStringToAppend = "<option id="  + searchTime + ">"+ pastResult.searchDate+ "," + purpose + "</option>"
$("#searchHistoryDropDownId").append(optionStringToAppend)
optionId= "#" + searchTime
console.log(optionId)
$(optionId).data("storedSearch", {searchPurpose: pastResult.searchPurpose, licensePlate:pastResult.licensePlate, startDate:pastResult.startDate,endDate:pastResult.endDate,longitude:pastResult.longitude,latitude:pastResult.latitude})
```

where, pastResult is passed in.

I then have a Backbone change event on `"#searchHistoryDropDown"`, and I have this code

```
populateForm:(event)=>
  selectedOption= $("#searchHistoryDropDownId option:selected")
  store = $(selectedOption).data("storedSearch")
  console.log(store)
```

I am getting an undefined in that console log, and I'm not sure why. How am I using the .data command wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that `#searchHistoryDropDownId option:selected` is the `<option>` that you added the data to? And `selectedOption` is already a jQuery object, you don't need to `$(selectedOption)`.

Comment: If you are using backbone, and the object is already passed to the view for render; is there a reason you are not just fetching the data directly from the object when the event triggers?